# regex for email validation

Tags: regex, email

I have written the regex below for a really simple email validation. I plan to send a confirmation link.

```
/.*@[a-z0-9.-]*/i
```

I would, however, like to enhance it from the current state because a string like this does not yield the desired result:

test ,my.name+test@gmail-something.co.uk, test

The "test ," portion is undesirably included in the match. I experimented with word boundaries unsuccessfully.

1. How should I modify?
2. Even though I've kept this simple, are there any valid email formats it would exclude?

THANKS!

Comment: This has been here so often... Have you looked at the questions you were shown after entering your title?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of . try matching every character except \s (whitespace):

```
/[^\s]*@[a-z0-9.-]*/i
```

Comment: To match everything except whitespace, shouldn't we match for (capital S) `\S`? Unless it doesn't work with all regex engines..

Comment: The ^ at the front of the square brackets means characters not in this list. As such it inverts the meaning f \s. I guess you could use /\S*@[a-z0-9.-]*/i instead.

Answer (score 22):

It's a ***lot*** more complicated !!!
See [Mail::RFC822::Address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) and be scared...very scared.

Comment: The first time i saw this Regex it scared me a lot, i showed it to a friend and he didn't believe me what it was THE EMAIL REGEX at first then he was also horrified. Good memories.

Comment: The Mail::RFC822::Address accepts much more than what is commonly known as an e-mail address. See the comment at the bottom that says: "This regular expression will only validate addresses that have had any comments stripped and replaced with whitespace". So it accepts whitespace.

Comment: well, I was ready to be horrified. But this is beyond Lovecraftian...

Answer (score 17):

**Don't use regular expressions to validate e-mail addresses**

Instead, from [mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list](https://web.archive.org/web/20090907143425/http://mail.python.org:80/pipermail/python-list/2006-September/404146.html)<sup>1</sup> written by Ben Finney.

> The best advice I've seen when people ask "How do I validate whether
>   an email address is valid?" was "Try sending mail to it".
>
> It's both Pythonic, and truly the best way. If you actually want to
>   confirm, don't try to validate it statically; *use* the email address,
>   and check the result.  Send an email to that address, and don't use it
>   any further unless you get a reply saying "yes, this is the right
>   address to use" from the recipient.
>
> The sending system's mail transport agent, not regular expressions,
>   determines which part is the domain to send the mail to.
>
> The domain name system, not regular expressions, determines what
>   domains are valid, and what host should receive mail for that domain.
>
> Most especially, the receiving mail system, not regular expressions,
>   determines what local-parts are valid.

*<sup><sup>1</sup>[This is original link before it went dead](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-September/404146.html)</sup>*

Comment: +1 for the link I would have posted (wish I could give +10!)

Comment: I think this is a good candidate for a Jeff and Joel podcast rant about what isn't an awesome answer.  Sometimes you may just want a heuristic to do something and 98 percent of the time, people with dumb email addresses can go spit.

Comment: "people with weird e-mail addresses can go spit"

You're fired.

Comment: Seriously, I'm not sure if it was a good idea, but I made a box for a response form that someone could enter a phone number or an email address in, if they entered something I thought was an email address (using regex) it'd put that email address in the reply to field in the header.  Semi-Handy!

Comment: Sometimes I tell websites with stupid regex checks to go spit; by never using them again. I need my gmail + syntax!

Comment: This link seems to be broken now.

Comment: When we say validate an email address we are talking about two things. 1. Is validating that it's a real email address (which you can validate by sending a confirmation link to the address. 2. Is the validation that most people are talking about. That is to use a regular expression to *assist* the user in entering an address. x@x.x is all you need. We're not here to validate whether imanidiot@yourmomshouse.lol is a real email address. Everyone against regex validation for email either don't understand the issue fully or are just complete trolls.

Comment: This works so long as you have a two-way system. However, if you have a configuration app for a system that can only send an email out but not receive any replies then you need to validate it statically as best you can.

Answer (score 14):

Almost nothing you use that is short enought to make sense looking at it will TRULY validate an email address. With that being said, here is what I typically use:

```
^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

It's actually the built in regex for ASP.NET's regular expression validator for email addresses.

NOTE: many of the regexes given in this thread MAY have worked in the 90's, but TLD's are allowed to be less than 2 characters and more than 4 characters in today's web environment. For example, info@about.museum IS a valid email address because .museum is one of those new, long TLDs.

Comment: '_' matches \w. But '_' is not allowed in domain names. Also we have now internationalized domain names (in arabic for example).

Comment: This does not check for spaces as "joe blogs@email.com" returns as a valid email.

Comment: @Weggo This does not allow spaces. If yours does, you might be missing the  caret (^) at the start

Comment: @Rick - your correct, I didn't have (^). I've +1 your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found that instead of matching the whole email-address against a regular expression, it is much more practical to just split the string at the @ and:

- First check for existing MX or A records of the domain part via a DNS-library.
- Then check the localpart (the part on the left hand side of the @) against a simpler regex.

The reason to do the DNS checking is that unreachable email-addresses albeit RFC-compliant are worth nothing. The reason for additionally checking the A-record is that they are used to determine where to deliver mail to when no MX record is found. (see RFC2821, 3.6)

Further tips:

- Use a robust DNS resolver library, do not roll your own. Test it against large companies. These sometimes have a huge number of mailservers, which can lead to problems. I've seen a buggy library crap out on bmw.com. Just saying. :)

Answer (score -1):

A smaller two step regex provides good results

/** check to see if email address is in a valid format.
     *  Leading character of mailbox must be alpha
     *  remaining characters alphanumeric plus -_ and dot
     *  domain base must be at least 2 characters
     *  domain extension must be at least 2, not more than 4 alpha
     *  Subdomains are permitted.
     *  @version 050208 added apostrophe as valid char
     *  @version 04/25/07 single letter email address and single 
     *  letter domain names are permitted.
     */
    public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String address){
        String sRegExp;

```
    // 050208 using the literal that was actually in place
    // 050719 tweaked 
    // 050907 tweaked, for spaces next to @ sign, two letter email left of @ ok
    // 042507 changed to allow single letter email addresses and single letter domain names
    // 080612 added trap and unit test for two adjacent @signs
    sRegExp =   "[a-z0-9#$%&]"          // don't lead with dot
        +   "[a-z0-9#$%&'\\.\\-_]*"     // more stuff dots OK
        +   "@[^\\.\\s@]"               // no dots or space or another @ sign next to @ sign
        +   "[a-z0-9_\\.\\-_]*"         // may or may  not have more character
        +   "\\.[a-z]{2,4}";            // ending with top level domain: com,. biz, .de, etc.

    boolean bTestOne =  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile( sRegExp,
            java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(address).matches();

    // should this work ?
    boolean bTwoDots =  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\.\\.",  // no adjacent dots
                    java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(address).find();

    boolean bDotBefore = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[\\.\\s]@", //no dots or spaces before @
                         java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(address).find();

    return bTestOne && !bTwoDots && !bDotBefore;
}   // end IsValidEmail
```

Answer (score -1):

this comes from Regex Buddy (definitely a need to buy prog!)

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

Comment: It does not matches .museum top level domain.