# Invalid email address using preg_match

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate an email in php5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php5)

I have used the following code to ensure email addresses provided on signup are valid.

```
(!preg_match("/^( [a-zA-Z0-9] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] )*@( [a-zA-Z0-9_-] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] +)+$/" , $email))
```

I entered a standard email address such as

> yourname@company.co.uk

and it is flagging up as being invalid.

Can anyone help me with why this may be happening?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261/test-expand-my-email-regex) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997078/email-regular-expression) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) ... [use search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+email)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not just use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
var_dump(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

EDIT

```
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
{
   echo 'Email is not valid';
}
else
{
   //do the stuff
}
```

Comment: Using this, what would it produce if it was false?

Comment: Could I just wrap it in an if statement, so if (var_dump(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))), then continue with the code?

Comment: @Luke: if the email address is not valid one it will return boolean false otherwise the email address itself

Comment: Thankyou for the code, I will test it now :)

Comment: Using that, it is stating a simple email address is invalid, hmmm. There must be something wrong with the passing of a variable!

Comment: @Luke: Just exercise here The running DEMO for you. http://codepad.org/E3RIsQG6

Comment: Cheers bud, was a sloppy piece of code by me that I hadn't fixed. All sorted now!

Answer (score 6):

Now can I ask *you* a question? What are those spaces doing in your regular expression? :-)

I'm pretty certain that spaces aren't actually valid in email addresses. And, even if they were, they wouldn't be required to be at specific positions relative to the separators (such as immediately before and after the `@` character).

Although I generally disagree with the use of regular expressions for email addresses (just send an email with a confirmation link - that solves your problem and then some <sup>a</sup>), you should at least use the right regular expression if you *must* do it that way.

---

<sup>a</sup> There are an untold number of perfectly valid email addresses that don't have an actual account behind them.

Comment: Agreed, and the correct email regex is quite ugly...

Comment: I took the code from a google search, I didn't write it myself. I can only assume that it has flaws. I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to use regex for matching emails, the following will match "sensible" addresses.

```
preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]+([_\.\-]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*){1}([@]){1}([a-z0-9]+([_\-]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*)+(([\.]{1}[a-z]{2,6}){0,3}){1}$/i', $email)
```

It's quite verbose but if you only want, like i said "sensible" addresses to pass - it does the job.

does get stuck on address like "example@**somename.somewhere**.com" because, after the @ symbol it looks for anything following a period to only be only 2-6 characters in length.

"example@**somename-somewhere**.com" however would pass fine.

I don't recommend trying to use a single regex solution for the job unless, as in my case, you only want to allow "sensible" addresses.

There is quite a good article that covers "correctly" validating email addresses here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

Answer (score -1):

With the new domainless addresses that are planned to be released, paxdiablo's solution seems even better