# Regex Expression for finding a string Which Has one @ and should not start with . or end with

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee, email-validation

Regex Expression for finding a string which has one `@` and should not start with `.` or end with `.` Meaning hello@Same is valid .hello@Same, hello@Same. and hello@sdj@same are all invalid

What is the problem in `(^([^@]+)@([^@])+$)(^[^\\.].*$)(^.*[^\\.]$)`.

All these three parts work individually but when we put together doesn't work

Comment: A good comment on the subject : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1076589/966590

Comment: Why would you not allow multiple @s or no starting dot? Both may be valid in email adresses.

Comment: Basically ... What i want to know is can i say an expression should match (patternA) && (patternB) && (patternC) and each of the pattern can be evaluated individually on expression .. each pattern should have its own start of line symbol and end of line symbol ... In the above example ... patternA evaluates only @ and patternB to doesn't start with . and then patternC to doesn't end with . .All work individually well how to combine all three at a place ?

Comment: And expression having the meaning patternA && patternB is `(?=patternA)patternB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just concatenate regular expressions if you want to match 
all of them.

Another thing that is wrong is trying to validate email addresses
with a regular expression. This just does not work well. The only 
way to find out if the user entered a valid adress is to send an 
email.

A regular expression that matches your specifications would be

```
^(?=[^@]+@[^@]+$)[^.].*[^.]$
```

but, as I said, thats not a great way to validate email adresses. [Check this link for horrible counter examples.](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx) =)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple start of line symbols `^` and multiple end of line symbols `$` in your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

```
^([^.@]+)@([^.@]+)$
```

To break it down to more manageable pieces:

```
^([^.@]+)  // Start with anything except . or @
@          // @ must be somewhere in the expression
([^.@]+)$  // End with anything except . or @
```

It doesn't match your specifications exactly (can't start or end with `@`) but that is probably a desirable attribute if you're validating email addresses.

Comment: This expressions allows multiple @ signs (e.g. @boo@boo@). Also, why are you using "[^@]|\w+" (either a single non-@ character, or one or more alphanumerics)? Thats not part of the OPs specs. =)

Comment: @Jens - Fixed the original problem but now there's another (currently doesn't allow for periods). I'll look at this again tomorrow morning. I'm beginning to see what you mean about this being a bad way to validate email addresses. 8)